# Variance of 1 over sum

Tags: variance, estimation, gamma-distribution

I was given to prove that if we're given statistics of Gamma distributed random variables $X_1,X_2...X_n$ (pdf $f_{\chi}(x,\alpha,\lambda)=\frac{{\lambda}^{\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}e^{-{\lambda}x}$) where $\alpha$ is known and had to prove that we can't find the efficient estimation for $\lambda$ argument.So i had to calculate the variance of $\frac{1}{\sum{X_i}}$ where i stuck.Could anybody give me a hint?

Comment: I'm sure you know that $\sum X_i$ also has a Gamma distribution.  Perhaps a little less well known is that you can work out its distribution explicitly and from that determine its variance: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution.